Keycloak Impersonate - unable to create OTP-Seeds or recovery-tokens for Users by impersonation
I would like to give a user “manager” the possibility to create OTP seeds or recovery tokens for other users. So the user “manager” should be able to burn hardware OTP tokens for users or provide users with an "emergency access" if they have forgotten their hardware tokens.
The “manager” user has the impersonation right.
If the “manager” user uses impersonation, he is also redirected to the user accout page and can customize the user data.
However, if the user “manager” wants to create an OTP seed or Recoery token, a login is displayed for the user who is being edited.
Question:
How do I configure keycloak so that the user “manager” can create OTP seeds and recovery tokens for other users without an additional login from the user?
By the way:
Is there a way to ensure that it really is the user when the user logs in for the first time (without OTP/recovery tokens)? E.g. via a predefined PIN that the user receives in a secure way?
